# Before Delete Test Class - Getting "De-reference Null Object error on other trigger"

Tags: apex, unit-test, customsetting, delete

I'm new to Apex and Code...

A trigger from a managed package is causing my test class to fail. Here's the code for the trigger causing the error:

```
trigger RAPID_SVMXC_BeforeInsertUpdateDelete_WorkDetails on SVMXC__Service_Order_Line__c (before insert, before update,before delete) {

Activate_Timesheet__c Activate_Timesheet   = new Activate_Timesheet__c();  // name of Custom Setting
Activate_Timesheet = Activate_Timesheet__c.getValues('TimesheetState');  // grab the specific setting

if (Activate_Timesheet.Enable_Timesheet__c==true || RAPID_SVMXC_TimesheetUtils_UT.TimesheetUtilsTest==true)
{
    if (trigger.isDelete) 
    {
        RAPID_SVMXC_TimesheetUtils.removeTimesheetEntriesFromWorkDetails(trigger.oldMap.keySet());
    }
    else
    {
        RAPID_SVMXC_TimesheetUtils.checkForWorkDetailOverlap(trigger.new,trigger.oldMap);
    }
}}
```

The error message is:

> caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Trigger.RAPID_SVMXC_BeforeInsertUpdateDelete_WorkDetails: line 7, column 1: []

Line 7 in that trigger is: if (Activate_Timesheet.Enable_Timesheet__c==true || RAPID_SVMXC_TimesheetUtils_UT.TimesheetUtilsTest==true)...

I can't figure out why it's causing this error if "Activate_Timesheet__c" is a Custom Setting, why is a missing lookup field on my record insert causing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create **custom setting** in your test class.

`Insert new Activate_Timesheet__c (field__c = value);`

Comment: And the reason for this is that Custom Setting data in an org is not available in unit tests. If you (OP) don't create the data, you'll get `null` back from `Activate_Timesheet__c.getValues('TimesheetState');`. That was the cause of the NPE you were getting.